# Corona SDK : Director Class and Grouping objects

Tags: android, ios, coronasdk

I've got a problem about Director class and grouping some objects on an external class. Here is my scripts of short example application.

[main.lua](http://goo.gl/XMyd9)

[gameScene.lua](http://goo.gl/7qFfe)

[fakeScene.lua](http://goo.gl/R3Vl8)

[theClass.lua](http://goo.gl/rbufd)

Do not be lazy to glance, scripts are very short :)

At the bottom of "theClass.lua" script, there is a line like that : "theGroup:insert(back)"

When I comment this line, there is no problem about application, but I need to group some objects in this theClass module. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try returning the variable into a table using

```
local function theFunc(localGroupValue)
 localGroup = localGroupValue
 local back = display.newImage("background.png")
 back:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
 back.x = 200
 back.y = 200

 return("back")

end

for s=1,#array do
 table.insert(array,theFunc())
end
```

and then insert the array into the group using

```
for s=1,#array do 
 theGroup:insert(array[s])
end
```